# ansi string to wide string without system api

Tags: c, cuda, widestring

I'm looking for a way to convert ANSI string to wide string, I need to do this in CUDA CPU code, so I cannot use system API like MultiByteToWideChar. I googled a lot but found nothing about implementing this from scratch.

I downloaded the source code of reactos and tried to read the detail of MultiByteToWideChar. It seems more complicated than I thought.

EDIT:
The character code is not limited to 0~127, it can be all kinds of language. But utf-8 is of no concern, it won't be in utf-8 format.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why can't you use a "system API"?

Comment: The code runs on GPU side, not on CPU. GPU code cannot call system API.

Comment: So why did you write " I need to do this in CUDA CPU code"?

Comment: My requirement is pretty strange but it's off topic.

Comment: If you are writing CPU code, whether you compile it the the CUDA toolchain or not, you can use any CPU System API you want. If you are writing GPU code, you can't. It isn't off-topic, it is absolutely core to your question. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the encoding you're using for your strings. If you're using plain US-ASCII strings (i.e. character code points 0 to 127), you could use something simple like this (of course you can/should add safety checks for NULL pointers and buffer length):

```
void charStrToWCharStr(wchar_t *dest, const char *src)
{
    while (*src != '\0')
        *dest++ = *src++;
}
```

Which is basically equivalent to a strcpy where the destination buffer is a wchar_t array. All src buffer characters are copied to the dest buffer, each character gets cast to wchar_t in the process.

If you're using multibyte encodings (like UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.), then you'll need something more sophisticated, like encoding conversion functions, depending on your input/output buffer text encodings.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the character code is not limited to 0~127, it can be all kinds of language. But utf-8 is of no concern, it won't be in utf-8 format.

Comment: You should clarify the encoding in use in your question. If you don't even know the source and target encoding, there's nothing that can be done to solve the problem.